# Push notification in react native for both ios and android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

There are 2 situations where I need to implement the best and most efficient way to push the notification to the end users:

1. specific users who are within a 10-mile radius of a business offering discounts will get notified about expiring coupons or any other new offers.
2. All of the Users get notified of the next upgrade feature available to install.

Please let me know if I should save all of the device tokens downloading my app in my DB along with their lat, lng So that I can search them for a specific distance before sending a notification. Or shall I just save registered users only for notification?

I am writing backend API for this app and need the best solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications need device token, so if you need to send the Notification to every user in the app, even if the user is not registered, you will need the device token in order to make the push notification work.

Also keep in mind that device token could change so you need to save it every time you can, for example, every time the app is launched.

For the notifications in the geofence I think you can use a local notification.